# Interpolating points on a sphere between two points

Tags: spherical-coordinates, geodesic, riemann-sphere

I managed to solve it using the following function:

given a cartesian point A and point B.

the geodesic path on a sphere is defined as:

r(t) = sin(1-t)*A + sin(t)*B, for t=[0, 1]

then normalize r(t)/||r(t)|| to get the points on a sphere

[image]

Can someone explain me why does it work?

- edit, changed the "1" to pi/2 to get uniform sampling
  [image]

Comment: Does your $\sin$ accept a different unit from radians or degrees?

Comment: it's in radians

Comment: Then $r(0) = \sin(1) A \approx 0.84A$ and $r(1) \approx 0.84 B$. I wonder what the intent of this geodesic path definition is.

Comment: you should normalize the output.

Comment: Interpolation by the common $(1-s)A + sB$ for $s\in[0,1]$ would give points on the chord between $A$ and $B$. Similarly, interpolation by 

$$\frac{r(t)}{\sin(1-t) + \sin(t)} = \frac{\sin(1-t)}{\sin(1-t) + \sin(t)}A + \frac{\sin(t)}{\sin(1-t) + \sin(t)}B$$

also would give points on the chord. The later normalisation makes the denominator unnecessary and scales points on the chord to the great circle.

Comment: You’re just plotting ((cos(t),sin(t))).

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a monotonic locus of $r(t)$ in both cases, however they are unrelated to the surface of the sphere. By normalising $r(t)$ afterwards to $\hat{r}(t)=\frac{r(t)}{\|r(t)\|}$, you're radially projecting your locus onto the unit *sphere* which gives you a *non-linear* parametrisation (non-linear interpolation). This non-linearity of parametrisation is visible in your plot. When you remove the sines there will be higher densities of points at the beginning and end of your locus than in the middle.

Comment: Yes I saw that, but then when I change the 1 to be pi/2 (both inside the sin and in the linspace) I got uniform density. I've edited the post

Comment: $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-t)=\cos(t)$ so try more $A$s and $B$s.

Comment: so why is linear combination of polar coordinates gives me the shortest path on a sphere?